# convert the result of by() function (a list) to data frame in R-Edited

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, group-by

I have data that looks like this :

```
   is_severe     encoding    sn_id
6           1        1   chr1 17689
7           0        2   chr1 17689
8           1        1   chr1 17689
9           1        2   chr1 69511
10          1        2   chr1 69511
11          1        1   chr1 69511
12          0        1   chr1 69511
```

I performed a statistical test on every "group" of values based on the sn_id column.

this is the function for the statistical  test:

```
catt <-

  function(y, x, score = c(0, 1, 2)) {
    miss <- unique(c(which(is.na(y)), which(is.na(x))))
    n.miss <- length(miss)
    if(n.miss > 0) {
      y <- y[-miss]
      x <- x[-miss]
    }
    if(!all((y == 0) | (y == 1))) 
      stop("y should be only 0 or 1.")
    if(!all((x == 0) | (x == 1) |(x == 2))) 
      stop("x should be only 0, 1 or 2.")
    ca <- x [y == 1]
    co <- x [y == 0]
    htca <- table(ca)
    htco <- table(co)
    A <- matrix(0, 2, 3)
    colnames(A) <- c(0, 1, 2)
    rownames(A) <- c(0, 1)
    A[1, names(htca)] <- htca
    A[2, names(htco)] <- htco
    ptt <- prop.trend.test(A[1, ], colSums(A), score = score) 
    p.value = as.numeric(ptt$p.value) 
    res=p.value
    return(res)}
```

and i performed it  on the groups of snp_id using the by function:

```
send=by(merged_df_normal,merged_df_normal$snp_id, function (merged_df_normal) {catt(merged_df_normal$is_sever_int,merged_df_normal$encoding)})
```

and got these results for example :

```
merged_df_normal$snp_id: chr11441806
[1] 0.6274769
--------------------------------------------------------------------- 
merged_df_normal$snp_id: chr1144192891
[1] NA
```

i wanted to transform this into a data frame which will look like this:

```
snp_id                     pvalue
chr11441806                  0.6274769
chr1144192891                 NA
```

I tried this :

```
do.call(rbind,list(send)
```

and it returned a matrix
that looks like this:

```
chr11441806      chr1144192891         
0.6274769          NA
```

I had to edit the function after accepting an answer :

```
catt_2 <-
  function(y, x, score = c(0, 1, 2)) {
    miss <- unique(c(which(is.na(y)), which(is.na(x))))
    n.miss <- length(miss)
    if(n.miss > 0) {
      y <- y[-miss]
      x <- x[-miss]
    }
    if(!all((y == 0) | (y == 1))) 
      stop("y should be only 0 or 1.")
    if(!all((x == 0) | (x == 1) |(x == 2))) 
      stop("x should be only 0, 1 or 2.")
    ca <- x [y == 1]
    co <- x [y == 0]
    htca <- table(ca)
    htco <- table(co)
    A <- matrix(0, 2, 3)
    colnames(A) <- c(0, 1, 2)
    rownames(A) <- c(0, 1)
    A[1, names(htca)] <- htca
    A[2, names(htco)] <- htco
    ptt <- prop.trend.test(A[1, ], colSums(A), score = score)
    res <- list(
                chisq = as.numeric(ptt$statistic), 
                 
                p.value = as.numeric(ptt$p.value)
                )
    return(res)
  }
```

and now the results are :

```
send=by(merged_df_normal,merged_df_normal$snp_id, function (merged_df_normal) {catt_2(merged_df_normal$is_sever,merged_df_normal$encoding)})


    merged_df_normal$snp_id: chr11007252
$chisq
[1] NA

$p.value
[1] NA

------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
merged_df_normal$snp_id: chr1100731820
$chisq
[1] 0.9111779

$p.value
[1] 0.3398021
```

and what I would like it to be is:

```
snp_id                     pvalue                chisq         
    chr11441806                  0.6274769       0.9111779
    chr1144192891                 NA              NA
```

the answer:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(merged_df_normal)

merged_df_normal[,.(p.value=catt(is_sever,encoding)),snp_id]
```

worked really well for getting just the p.value  but is there a way to edit the above answer and add a new column chisq? thank you for the help the previous answer

Comment: Prefer `ave` or `aggregate` in that case.

Comment: @Maël - tried aggregate(merged_df_normal,list(merged_df_normal$snp_id), function (merged_df_normal) {catt(merged_df_normal$is_sever_int,merged_df_normal$encoding)})   gave error :Error in merged_df_normal$is_sever_int : 
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can just apply `catt()` to each group of `sn_id`. Let's say your original data is called `df`. Then, you can do the following:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[,.(p.value=catt(is_severe,encoding)),sn_id]
```

You need to adjust your function so that it handles `sn_id` groups that don't have sufficient data; in your example data frame, `catt()` only runs without error on `sn_id == chr1 69511`..

In general, however, the output will look like this, with one row in the frame for each `sn_id` value

```
        sn_id   p.value
       <char>     <num>
1: chr1 69511 0.2482131
```

Comment: is the result a data frame?

Comment: yes it will be a data frame with one row per sn_id. Again, you need to make sure that your  `catt()` function handles potential problems.. For example, it will error out if you submit `x` and `y` vectors of length=1.. Maybe your actual data has no such problems, but your example data does (most of the sn_ids in your example have only one row)

Comment: it returns something strang : setDT(df)
Error in setDT(df) : 
  Argument 'x' to 'setDT' should be a 'list', 'data.frame' or 'data.table'
>

Comment: I used `df` in my example. What is the name of your data that you posted in the example - is it a dataframe? Perhaps it is called `merged_df_normal`?  That is the data.frame that you want to set to data.table.. try `setDT(merged_df_normal)`

Comment: yes the data os called merged_df_normal i tried this:my_data=merged_df_normal[,.(p.value=catt(merged_df_normal$is_sever,merged_df_normal$encoding)),merged_df_normal$snp_id]  but it has been running over 2 hours (and hasnt stopped yet) , my data is very large but when i applied BY function it took 10 minutes is there any other way to do so?

Comment: that is not the approach i provided above. Do not refer to the data frame inside the brackets. Look again at my solution.

Comment: thank you for your help:) would really appreciate if you could help with the edited question after accepting your answer which worked great

Comment: We are not supposed to build on questions...(Better to ask a new question). However, you can do something simple like this: `df[,catt_2(is_severe,encoding),sn_id]`