# preforming a function on grouped data in R

Tags: r, function, error-handling, group-by

i have data that looks like this : it has  812222 rows

```
X            snp_id         is_severe encoding_1 encoding_2 encoding_0
1     0  GL000191.1-37698         0          0          1          7
2     1  GL000191.1-37698         1          0          2         11
3     3 GL000192.1-100085         0          5          3          0
4     4 GL000192.1-100085         1          3         10          0
```

i have a function that preforms a Cochran-Armitage trend test:

```
catt <-
  function(y, x0,x1,x2, score = c(0, 1, 2)) {
    h=data.frame(is_severe=c(0,1),
                 encod_0=c(0,0),
                 encod_1=c(0,0),
                 encod_2=c(0,0)
    )
    h$is_severe=y
    h$encod_0=x0
    h$encod_1=x1
    h$encod_2=x2
    my_mat <- as.matrix(h)
    A <- matrix(0, 2, 3)
    colnames(A) <- c(0, 1, 2)
    rownames(A) <- c(0, 1)
    A[1,] =my_mat[1,2:4]
    A[2, ]=my_mat[2,2:4]
    ptt <- prop.trend.test(A[1, ],colSums(A), score = score) 
    
    res <- list(
      chisq = as.numeric(ptt$statistic), 
      
      p.value = as.numeric(ptt$p.value)
    )
    return(res)
  
    }
```

i want to perform this test on every value of snp_id column
i tried by the by() function it worked very well but it returned results not in data frame
:

```
by(union,union$snp_id, function (union) {catt(union$is_severe,union$encoding_0,union$encoding_1,union$encoding_2)})

union$snp_id: chr17-3343519
$`2x3-table`
  0 1 2
0 1 6 1
1 8 4 1

$chisq
[1] 3.47929

$p.value
[1] 0.0621414

------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
union$snp_id: chr17-33445549
$`2x3-table`
   0 1 2
0 11 2 0
1  8 0 0

$chisq
[1] 1.360324

$p.value
[1] 0.2434814
```

so i tried this :

```
library("data.table")
setDT(union)
union[,.(chisq=catt(union$is_severe,union$encoding_0,union$encoding_1,union$encoding_2)[1],p.value=catt(union$is_severe,union$encoding_0,union$encoding_1,union$encoding_2)[2]),snp_id]
```

it returned :

```
union[,.(chisq=catt(union$is_severe,union$encoding_0,union$encoding_1,union$encoding_2)[1],p.value=catt(union$is_severe,union$encoding_0,union$encoding_1,union$encoding_2)[2]),snp_id]
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "is_severe", value = c(0L, 1L, 0L,  : 
  replacement has 812222 rows, data has 2
>
```

the out put of the function is 2 values :

```
res <- list(
      chisq = as.numeric(ptt$statistic), 
      
      p.value = as.numeric(ptt$p.value)
    )
    return(res)
```

is there any way to fix this ?
thank you:)

Comment: res is a list. You cannot expect to have a dataframe yet you are returning a list from your function. Probably you should consider returning a vector or a dataframe instead of a list]

Comment: @onyambu based it on this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74056233/convert-the-result-of-by-function-a-list-to-data-frame-in-r-edited/74056608?noredirect=1#comment130827412_74056608

Comment: The previous one, all the values in the list were of the same size, here you have a matrix, and 2 numbers. ie a list of three but each element of the list is not of same size. No way to aggregate that into a dataframe

Comment: @onyambu but the result is not a matrix , it is only 2 values ( the matrix was just for  
 better understanding the function ) the out put is only this :res <- list(
      chisq = as.numeric(ptt$statistic), 
      
      p.value = as.numeric(ptt$p.value)
    )
    return(res)

Comment: in that case use the code in the llink you provided

Comment: @onyambu i used it but it returns the error i posted in the question

Answer (score 0):

You could nest by the snp_id and then run the test across the group and then unnest the results:

```r
library(tidyverse)

union |>
  nest(data = -snp_id) |>
  mutate(trend = map(data, ~catt(.x$is_severe, 
                                 .x$encoding_0, 
                                 .x$encoding_1,
                                 .x$encoding_2)))|>
  unnest_wider(trend) |>
  select(-data)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   snp_id             chisq p.value
#>   <chr>              <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 GL000191.1-37698  0.0337  0.854 
#> 2 GL000192.1-100085 3.26    0.0708
```

EDIT

I tried to speed it up. Still not sure how fast it will be for you. My thought was to run this in parallel. Also, I modified your `catt` function to make it more streamline.

```r
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

catt <- function(data, 
                 id, 
                 score = c(0,1,2), 
                 vars = c("encoding_0", "encoding_1", "encoding_2")){
  dat <- data[data$snp_id == id,]
  A <- as.matrix(dat[,vars])
  ptt <- suppressWarnings(prop.trend.test(A[1, ],colSums(A), score = score)) 
  data.frame(snp_id = dat$snp_id[1],
             chisq = as.numeric(ptt$statistic), 
             p.value = as.numeric(ptt$p.value))
}

ids <- unique(union$snp_id)

ncore <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(ncore-2)
registerDoParallel(cl)

output <- foreach(i = 1:length(ids), .combine = 'rbind' ) %dopar% {
  catt(union, ids[i])
}

stopCluster(cl) 

output
#>              snp_id      chisq    p.value
#> 1  GL000191.1-37698 0.03365385 0.85444507
#> 2 GL000192.1-100085 3.26377589 0.07082586
```

Comment: thank you for the solution.i was wondering if there is another way: my data is large: 812222 rows and It currently has been running for 3 hours ... still waiting for the results. thank you:_)

Comment: hmmm. Let me see if I can speed it up. 812222 isn't really too large, so maybe it is the `catt` function. give me ~30 mins.

Comment: okay @ElizaRomanski, I updated. Let me know if this is faster.

Comment: I tried your update   but it has been running for 3 hours .... no results yet .

Comment: Okay well I gave it a shot. The solution works. Your issue is just computation time. Is sounds like you're running this on your local computer. Push it to some cloud computing and run it through more cores and threds.